# How to send traffic to only one Pod in a Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a Deployment with 3 Pods, but that only one of them receives traffic. If this Pod goes down, then the ClusterIP Service should route new requests to one of the remaining Pods (which act like a backup Pods for availability only) and it will act as the new "Primary".

How can it be achieved?

Comment: What is your objective here? Are you perhaps looking for a `StatefulSet`?

Comment: Perhaps.. If StatefulSet can achieve what I need (I don't need data replication), then it can be a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your pod definition to contain a [leader election sidecar container](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/contrib/tree/master/election) and achieve this with a [readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes).

Only the leader in the group of pods will return a valid status for the readiness probe port. A kubernetes `service` resource will only route requests to pods that are reporting ready.

When one pod terminates, another leader election will take place, the selected pod's readiness will activate, and the `service` will begin routing traffic to the newly elected leader.

Example probe definition (container checking whether it is leader).

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - curl -v --silent http://localhost:4040/ 2>&1 | grep $HOSTNAME
```

Comment: Could you show a full demonstration for Redis Deployment and Service?